# Como acessar o dado de um subArray com Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Preciso acessar o dado de um subarray via javascript, eu consigo atualmente acessar o conteúdo de todo o array:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu preciso pegar no caso é o `codigoImpressora` que esta dentro do `subarray impressoraPedido` porém não estou conseguindo encontrar nada que me auxilie nisso.

Conteúdo do Array:

```
{
"empresa":"testes",
"itensPedido":
[
{"impressoraPedido":
{"persistenceId":2,
"persistenceId_string":"2",
"persistenceVersion":0,
"persistenceVersion_string":"0",
"codigoImpressora":"2",
"codEmpresa":3,
"patrimonio":"1327",
"modeloImpressora":"T644",
"setorinstalacao":"Depósito peças"},
"suprimentoPedido":
{"persistenceId":3,
"persistenceId_string":"3",
"persistenceVersion":0,
"persistenceVersion_string":"0",
"codigoModeloImpressora":"2",
"codigoModeloSuprimento":2,
"nomeSuprimento":"TONER LEXMARK T644",
"codModeloSuprimento":"64418XL"},
"quantidadePedido":1}
]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só acessar na hierarquia que os dados se encontram.

Perceba que `itensPedido` é um *array*, dentro dele tem um objeto `impressoraPedido` e dentro deste objeto é que tem o que você precisa.

```js
const obj = 
{  
   empresa: "testes",
   itensPedido: [  
      {  
         impressoraPedido: {  
            persistenceId: 2,
            persistenceId_string: "2",
            persistenceVersion: 0,
            persistenceVersion_string: "0",
            codigoImpressora: "2",
            codEmpresa: 3,
            patrimonio: "1327",
            modeloImpressora: "T644",
            setorinstalacao: "Depósito peças"
         },
         suprimentoPedido: {  
            persistenceId: 3,
            persistenceId_string: "3",
            persistenceVersion: 0,
            persistenceVersion_string: "0",
            codigoModeloImpressora: "2",
            codigoModeloSuprimento: 2,
            nomeSuprimento: "TONER LEXMARK T644",
            codModeloSuprimento: "64418XL"
         },
         quantidadePedido: 1
      }
   ]
};

console.log(obj.itensPedido[0].impressoraPedido.codigoImpressora);

// Ou, se tiver mais de um item no array

for(let itemPedido of obj.itensPedido) {
    console.log(itemPedido.impressoraPedido.codigoImpressora);
}
```

Comment: Isso já me ajudou de certa forma, mas como posso fazer, por exemplo quando eu tiver duas linhas, assim como coloquei na imagem, no exemplo que você deu funcionou corretamente quando tem uma linha mas quando tiver duas ou mais como vou conseguir pegar o objeto "codigoImpressora" respectivo de cada linha?

Comment: Você comentou bem na hora que eu estava editando, rs. Só olhar o final da resposta.

Comment: Ali ele trouxe duas vezes o número 2 por qual motivo? Outra coisa, como eu vou ter que exibir no segundo dropdown apenas o conteudo respectivo ao primeiro dorpdown selecionada, como eu poderia adicionar cada retorno da minha verificação a uma variável?

Comment: Ele mostrou duas vezes porque tem dois `console.log` - são dois exemplos. Não entendi a segunda pergunta, não é o caso de [criar uma nova pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)?

Comment: pode ser, obrigado pela ajuda até agora :)

Comment: Criei uma nova pergunta para tentar me explicar melhor sobre minha necessidade agora: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209693/preencher-conteudo-de-segundo-dropdown-de-acordo-com-o-valor-do-primeiro-selecio